# iOS StoreKit Transaction Identifier does not match Receipt

Tags: ios, storekit, receipt-validation

I'm using the receipt to validate a purchase after I get the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` notification, and among other things get the expiration date for the subscription the user just purchased.

To properly identify the transaction that just occurred in the receipt, I'm matching it by the `transaction.transactionIdentifier` and `transaction_id`. The problem I'm encountering is that the transaction identifiers never match up.

I've been able to identify the correct transaction in the receipt by manually inspecting the `purchase_date` and `product_id`, but the `transaction_id` completely differs from the Transaction.

I've also looked at `transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier` and `original_transaction_id`, but none of these four values seem to match up at any point.

What is going on here? Anyone had similar issues when testing in sandbox? The documentation clearly states that the `transaction_id` should match the `transactionIdentifier` property of the transaction. Could this be a bug?

**Edit 1:**
Here's the different transaction identifiers for a single purchase of a subscription (that had previously expired)

```
transaction.transactionIdentifier = 1000000325087359
transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier = 1000000297785006
transaction_id = 1000000325087377
original_transaction_id = 1000000297785006
```

It seems as though the original transaction identifiers match up (why would they, it's a new purchase?), but the two others do not. Where do they come from and what do they match? I don't understand the relationship between the two and their significance.

Comment: I encount the same problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165228/why-could-not-find-transaction-record-on-the-server-side-in-apple-app-purchase

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`SKPaymentTransaction.transactionIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1411288-transactionidentifier) notes:

> This value has the same format as the transaction’s `transaction_id` in
>   the receipt; however, the values may not be the same.

And the documentation for [`transaction_id`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/transaction_id) notes:

> This value has the same format as the transaction’s
>   `transactionIdentifier` property; however, the values may not be the
>   same.
>
> You can use this value to:
>
> • Manage subscribers in your account
>   database. Store the `transaction_id`, `original_transaction_id`, and
>   `product_id` for each transaction, as a best practice to store
>   transaction records for each customer. App Store generates a new value
>   for `transaction_id` every time the subscription automatically renews or
>   is restored on a new device.
>
> • Differentiate a purchase transaction from
>   a restore or a renewal transaction. In a purchase transaction, the
>   `transaction_id` always matches the `original_transaction_id`. For
>   subscriptions, it indicates the first subscription purchase. For a
>   restore or renewal, the `transaction_id` does not match the
>   `original_transaction_id`. If a user restores or renews the same
>   purchase multiple times, each restore or renewal has a different
>   `transaction_id`.

I'll also note that the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) (from the Documentation Archive) states under Transaction Identifier:

> This value corresponds to the transaction’s `transactionIdentifier`
>   property.

It's not clear to me in what scenarios the two fields are or are not the same except in the documented scenarios.

Comment: your answer help me a lot but I just wonder if the transaction id did not match in the subscribe, how to identify the transaction? how to match the transaction on the server side in retore workflow?@Jordan H